# react-native : update state then check with addListener

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to update state then `check the state` with the 'addListener' in the 'componentDidMount'

When I update my state, I can see that my state is successfully updated but the `addListener` won't update.

I think I should see the `console.log('state is the same')` when I update my state but noting is happening.

Any Ideas?

This is my code:

```
export default class Update extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      number:1,
      newNumber:undefined
    }
    console.log(this.state.number, 'number')
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
      //when screen is loaded I get this console.
      if(this.state.number != this.state.newNumber){
        console.log('state is not the same')
      }
      //when I update state I should see this console log but nothing is happening.
      if(this.state.number == this.state.newNumber){
        console.log('state is the same')
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Button title='update' onPress={()=> this.setState({newNumber:1}, ()=> console.log(this.state.newNumber, 'newNumber'))}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to execute a function after state has been updated?

Comment: I want the `console.log('state is the same')` to be printed when I press the button

Comment: this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus') is called whenever your screen is focuesed after coming from other screen. So what do you want exactly, tell , i can help

Comment: change `willFocus` into `didFocus`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am updating my state in one screen. should I not use .addListener? I want to check whenever I change my state.

Comment: @kirimi just check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to achieve is to check that onClick of button , there is a newState which is set , and you want to check with existing one , did it update correctly or not.

So you are using `this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus')` which gets called when the screen is focused while coming from other screens. but in your case you are in the same screen and you update the state by calling the button, so it wont get called.

Rather react has its own lifecylce method called componentDidUpdate , and if you check the condition there for any state updates you will achieve it.

Please find below code and also expo link,

```
export default class Update extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      number:1,
      newNumber:undefined
    }
    console.log(this.state.number, 'number')
  }


  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.number != this.state.newNumber){
       alert('state is not the same')
      }
      //when I update state I should see this console log but nothing is happening.
      if(this.state.number == this.state.newNumber){
       alert('state is the same')
      }
  }



  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Button title='update' onPress={()=> this.setState({newNumber:1}, ()=> console.log(this.state.newNumber, 'newNumber'))}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

expo link [expo](https://snack.expo.io/S17jL6uRS)

hopeit helps, feel free for doubts

Comment: glad it helped, do mark as accepted if you think this was the correct answer so that it can help others

Answer (score 0):

the reason why your code wont work is because you want to listen to state changes but your listener only listen to navigation changes which only triggered when the screen will focus.

to detect the changes to your state in class component, you can always use the lifecycle of react which is `componentDidUpdate`

what you can do perhaps something like this.

```js
export default class Update extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      number:1,
      newNumber: null
    }
    console.log(this.state.number, 'number')
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.check()
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if(prevState.newNumber !== this.state.newNumber) {
      this.check()
    }
  }
  
  check = () => {
    if(this.state.number != this.state.newNumber){
      console.log('state is not the same')
    } else {
      console.log('state is the same')
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Button title='update' onPress={()=> this.setState({newNumber:1}, ()=> console.log(this.state.newNumber, 'newNumber'))}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```